# Where is anbox share folder with ubuntu

Tags: directory, sharing, anbox

i have installed anbox in my ubuntu distro.i want to install share files in anbox and i do not now how to share with anbox from ubuntu.and how to share data from anbox to ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

If you have installed anbox using snap on ubuntu, you can find Android folders at place

> /var/snap/anbox/common/data/media/0
>
> Note : sudo permission should be required to access above path.